# Setting Menu Title from Custom ListView Adapter

Tags: android, android-listview

I would like to know if there is any way of changing the MenuItem title from a ListView's button on click listener. The ListView onClickListener is in a custom adapter.

I was hoping that I could just do something like this:

```
Menu menu = (Menu) context.getMenu();

MenuItem quantity = (MenuItem) menu.findItem(R.id.action_cart);
quantity.setTitle("10");
```

but to no avail.

Any idea's?

Comment: define setMenuItem() in activity and call it from adapter.

Comment: Hi Ketan, could you elaborate as to where I implement setMenuItem(). I am still getting used to android development.

Comment: You know how to change menu item title..right ? then post that code here.

Comment: Sure I can change it in my Activity with quantity.setTitle() but that is not available to me in the custom adapter. The listener is in the adapter which means I would somehow need to get the Menu there so that I can set the title again. My problem lies with line 1 of my code. I dont know how to instantiate the menu inside the custom adapter. I hope I am making sense :(

Comment: have a look at my answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

define setMenuItem() in activity and call it from adapter.

```
public static void setMenuItem(String title){

   Menu menu = (Menu) context.getMenu();

   MenuItem quantity = (MenuItem) menu.findItem(R.id.action_cart);
   quantity.setTitle(title);

 }
```

now call this method in adapter as YourActivity.setMenuItem("Your Title");

Comment: Oh snap, thanks a million Ketan. I don't know why but I thought that it was a build in method that I just need to apply. Thanks, you are a rockstar chap!